# KDE Menu not showing application logo

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I have Android Studio app installed on Ubuntu 20.04 with KDE Plasma. The logo of this app does not appear in the menu of applications (Development) of Application Launcher.

How can I make it appear?

I am using KDE Plasma version 5.18.5.

Here follows a picture link of what I am talking about. As you can see the logos for Android Studio and JetBrains Toolbox do not appear.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? Which version of kde are you using? Which menu are you talking about? Please provide enough details, so that one can find an adequate answer. Please [edit] accordingly.

Comment: @someone Thanks. Just added the information for a better understanding of the problem I am facing.

Comment: Maybe it is an icon pack problem, can you try another icon pack? @someone

Comment: @TD15 Thanks. What do you mean by trying another icon pack? The only place where the logos are not displayed is where I mentioned them.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: I mean maybe use an icon pack from discover and check if the issue persists or not.

Also may I ask why install Ubuntu to use KDE? You could use eitheir Kubuntu or KDE neon for latest KDE version. @lbarqueira

Comment: @TD15 Didn`t work. I began to have ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome. Meanwhile, I am trying KDE Desktop to figure out if there are advantages. I may conclude at this point that I am satisfied with KDE Desktop. So my configuration, for now, is Ubuntu + KDE Desktop.

Comment: I can't help with the situation, but maybe this will:
https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=124403

I'm running plasma 5.23.4 On Kubuntu and never got this weird issue. @lbarqueira

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me with appimages. What I notice is that in that case the app cannot be seen in KDE Menu Editor (point 3 below). But I can see it in the application launcher and can add an icon (point 2 below). (That might not be remembered though, so better try multiple solutions.)

---

**1. Try different icon sets** for Plasma if you want.

Type 'icons' in your app launcher or go to Icons under System Settings - Appearance (etc, depending on Plasma version).

[image]

But most probably the problem is with the app itself.

**2. Try edit the app launcher and add an icon**. Find app in application launcher, right click and select "edit application".

[image]

If your app has no icon it might be editable there:

[image]

**3. Try edit the app launcher or create a new one.**
Right click the app launcher panel icon and select "Edit applications"** to open KDE Menu Editor.

[image: ![enter image description here]

There, look for your application and edit the icon by clicking it. You can also add new items and edit command and icon. You might need to do that in your case, if it's similar to mine, as said at the beginning. You can also download an icon from the web and point to that.

[image]

What that does is edit/create an application `.desktop` file launcher of the form `/home/YOUR_USERNAME/.local/share/applications/YOUR_APP.desktop` that you can also edit manually.

Creating a new launcher for your app in KDE Menu Editor may create a new entry in your application launcher menu

You can even look into `usr/share/applications`, open the corresponding file in Kate, edit the `Icon=` line and save as root. But it's better to simply copy that into `~/.local/share/applications` and edit it there.

Comment: It is working for me with appimages. I tried to solve the issue following your explanation and it still not working for Android Studio app and  JetBrains Toolbox.